# How to login to sandbox account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I would like to test my paypal payment.

I have logged into https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accounts and created two accounts

1 - personal account for buyer account with user "mymail-buyer@..."
2 - business account for seller with user "mymail-seller@..."

I tried to use my website (which sells in the name of mymail-seller@...") and to buy as if I am paying with "mymail-buyer@..." account.

However, I could not login.

Moreover, I tried entering directly to paypal with buyer/seller accounts - NONE worked.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. The mistake was that I tried to use the regular link for paypal. In fact, I should have logged in via this one:  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_about-accounts/ to modify password for these two sandbox account, after that, try to purchase item again or try to login sandbox.paypal.com.